# ORA-01003:no statement parsed

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

Working with tibco application.

Run the tibco application.

Without stopping the tibco program, go to sql prompt and rename the    table that application is using. Now, execute query and as
   expected,    we will see the error: "table or view does not exist".
   (<-- EXPECTED)

Rename the table back and again tibco app queries the table again.
   This time, you get the error: java.sql.SQLException:
   [tibcosoftwareinc][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01003:no statement 
   parsed

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why on earth would you do that?

Comment: What vendor/version of JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: I don't know. In tibco global variables I see - JDBCConnection driver - tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oracle.OracleDriver. In tibco\tpcl\5.6\jdbc I see  - TIoracle.jar. How can I know version of JDBC driver?

Answer (score -1):

Use this command:

```
java -jar ojdbc6.jar -getversion
```

to get the JDBC driver version.  Also, you can check the `MANIFEST.MF` file to check the version.